# To check which resource is being used by which process

Tags: linux, ubuntu, resources, monitoring, selinux

I have few processes running on my system. I need to list out which of the process, at a moment, has acquired/is using one or more of these in my system:

1. Ethernet
2. Camera
3. USB
4. Bluetooth
5. WiFi
6. File System

etc.

Is there a way to find this out ?

Language : C/C++

Platform : Ubuntu/Fedora (Allowed to have SELinux as well if required to implement the above)

Comment: Do you want this facility as a library function for C/C++ or you will be happy with a shell facility? In the latter case the *lsof* programm should answer most of your requests.

Comment: @begemotv2718 Thanks. Can you please post it as an answer, I would like to accept it.

Comment: Can this be done as a library call as well ?